# how to call BootStrap.groovy closure from controller

Tags: grails, groovy

I am new in groovy so i want to call Closure of BootStrap.groovy file from different controller.
Can any one please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`BootStrap.groovy` is meant to be called as your application starts up and shuts down. If you need reusable functionality, put that code into your own class or service and then call it both from your `BootStrap.groovy` as well as from your controller.

Comment: hi Petrin, Actually There is a Bean have settings of customer. And i used Multitenant plugin i want to getemail address for particular  user

Comment: You can use beans in `BootStrap.groovy` in the same way you use them in controllers, command objects and services: just `def myBean` them inside the `BootStrap` class.

Comment: but i dont have tenant Id to find which customer.

Comment: how we find current customer

Comment: Please update your question with more information or open another one - I gave you an answer to the question as it currently stands and right now I don't have enough information to help you with MultiTenant plugin problems.

Comment: ok problem is not multitenant. i just need to get id of logged in customer.

Comment: Depends a lot on what security solution you are using (Spring Security, Shiro, own implementation..) that's why I wrote that you need to update the question with more information.

Comment: one things i know can we call BootStrap closure from controller

Comment: ...see my answer :) Otherwise `BootStrap` is just a class so if you expose a closure (make it a public property of the class) then I guess you could call it, but I would consider that bad practice.

Comment: is it possible to make public closure

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make a public closure. Google how or open another question: it is against Stack Overflow rules to answer new questions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The way to invoke the `init` closure in `BootStrap` is no different than the way you invoke any other closure...

```
`new BootStrap().init(null)`
```

That addresses the question as asked, but there really is no good reason to ever do that.  It isn't clear what you are really trying to do but almost certainly the solution should not involve re-invoking code that is in `BootStrap`.  You probably want a filter or an interceptor to do some work.